# How do I access properties of a JSON document using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Using `JavaScript`, how can I access the `area` variable in the `JSON` document below?

```
{

  "foo : age=39, height=170": {
  "age": 39,
  "height": 172,
  "center": {
     "area": 102,
     "local": 304
  },
  "color": "#0000ff",
  "radius": 9.5,
  "color_srv": "#aa0054"
 }
}
```

Comment: We can't read minds, be clear with your question. What is the `number` variable??? what language are you using???

Comment: Can you please be more precise and clear ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the whole property string for the access, even if it look a bit strange.

```js
var data = {
    "foo : age=39, height=170": {
        "age": 39,
        "height": 172,
        "center": {
            "area": 102,
            "local": 304
        },
        "color": "#0000ff",
        "radius": 9.5,
        "color_srv": "#aa0054"
    }
};
document.write(data['foo : age=39, height=170'].center.area);
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to fix up that `JSON`, the format is invalid as it stands...

If you were to change it to something like this...

```
{
    "foo": {
        "age": 39,
        "height": 172,
        "center": {
            "area": 102,
            "local": 304
        },
        "color": "#0000ff",
        "radius": 9.5,
        "color_srv": "#aa0054"
    }
}
```

You could access that variable using the `JavaScript` below...

```
console.log(testing["foo"]["center"]["area"])
```